# How to multiple links jQuery content loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got an approach to load content from separate html files, but only useful for a single link destination, as code below:

**index.html**

```
<div class="nav-section" id="navID">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Follow</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

 <div id="divID">Content A</div>
```

**about.html**

```
<div class="nav-section" id="navID">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Follow</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

 <div id="divID">Content A</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navID ul li a').click(function() {
        $('#divID').load('destination.html #divID' + $(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

I have 4 links in index.html, which trying to load from multiple html files (i.e. example.html), I am in need of a solution to not repeating myself in JS but to load content from different links in accordance to the link destination. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
<li><a href="" data-html="destination.html">Home</a></li>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navID ul li a').click(function() {
        var html=$(this).data('html');
        $('#divID').load(html+' #divID' + $(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This actually solve the problem I am having, I appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navID ul li a').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "some.php",
            success: function(data, status) {
                $('#divID').html(data);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of what you're trying to do:

```
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/11111000000/syv2xv0w/

Comment: I must admit this looks pretty good, and worth trying. Thanks for the solution  buddy.